# Server constantly running a function to update a cache, will it block all other server functions?

Tags: node.js, service, redis, architecture, microservices

About once a minute, I need to cache all orderbooks from various cryptocurrency exchanges. There are hundreds of orderbooks, so this update function will likely never stop running.

My question is: If my server is constantly running this orderbook update function, will it block all other server functionality? Will users ever be able to interact with my server?

Do I need to create a separate service to perform the updating, or can Node somehow prioritize API requests and pause the caching function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: If my server is constantly running this orderbook
>   update function, will it block all other server functionality? Will
>   users ever be able to interact with my server?

If you are writing asynchronously, these actions will go into your eventloop and your node server would pick next event from eventloop while these actions are being performed. If you have too many events like this, your event queue would be long and user would face really slow response or may even get a timeout

> Do I need to create a separate service to perform the updating, or can
>   Node somehow prioritize API requests and pause the caching function?

Node only consumes event from the event queue. There are no priorities.

From the design perspective, you should look for options which can reduce this write load like bulkCreate/edit or if you are using redis for cache, consider [redis pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining)

Comment: Can you help me understand how redis pipeline would help? It seems like I would make all of my API calls, write the responses to a javascript object in memory, then use redis pipeline to write them in bulk to my redis db. So it seems like the amount of writing doesn't change, just when it's written. Is that correct?

Comment: `amount` would remain the same but the time to write it would reduce significantly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended question much of which depends on your system. In general your server should be able to handle concurrent requests, but there are some things to watch out for.

Performance costs. If the operation to retrieve and store data requires too much computational power, then it will cause strain on all requests processed by the server.

Database connections. The server spends a lot of time waiting for database queries to complete. If you have one database connection for the entire application, and this connection is busy, they will have to wait until the database connection is free. You may want to look into database connection 'pooling'.